# How to get the error code of WMP plugin in IE when it fails to play some resource?

Tags: javascript, windows, ocx, wmp

Recently I'm trying to make a web page for WMP troubeshooting.And what I want to do is, if the vistors cannot play the resource on my page because of some problems such as missing WMP codec,failing to pass DRM...etc, then I'll show them some information about how to fix it.I've googled **[an example](http://codepad.org/E3oho47q)** and the problem is the property `ErrorCode` of the WMP object `wmpocx` always comes up as `undefined` while it do exist there.So how can I get the WMP error code in JSCript?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution by reading the source code of  the [Security component upgrade](http://drmlicense.one.microsoft.com/Indivsite/zh-cn/indivit.asp) page on Microsoft's website.

Main code:

```
var error = wmpocx.error;
var errorItem;
var index;    //index into the error queue.
var message;

//The error is an error object that can have multiple errors in a queue
//error.errorCount is the count of errors in the error queue
for(index=0; index<error.errorCount; index++)
{
    errorItem = wmpocx.error.item(index);
    //you can get information on the error with the following properties
    //errorItem.errorCode
    ecode = errorItem.errorCode;
    message = errorItem.errorDescription;
}
```